# Is there a word for "able to be conducted"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means that something is able to be conducted, like heat or electricity, but more generally/in a metaphorical sense? "Conductible" means "able to conduct" which is counter intuitive.

Comment: I agree that it would perhaps be more intuitive if "conductible" meant "able to be conducted" especially since we have the word "conducive" to describe something that is "able to conduct," but nobody claimed that the English language was entirely intuitive.

Comment: What sense (or senses) of [*conduct*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conduct) are you concerned with? You mention heat and electricity (which is specific), but you then add *generally* and *metaphorically*. What is it that you're trying to express? Please provide a definition of your use of the word, as well as one or more example sentences with spaces where the word would fit.

Comment: He's a great musician, but he is so smug he never listens to anyone. He's perfect for solo gigs, but don't put him in an orchestra- he's just not conductible.

Comment: The only definition of **conductible** I've found is
_capable of being conducted_ {[Wordwebonline.com](https://www.wordwebonline.com/en/CONDUCTIBLE)}. I suspect OED will endorse this sense (and probably the one you mention also).

Comment: @jim - I've known people like that (prima donnas).  I think they're not *conductable* (like *educable*).

Comment: Jake: *fluid*?  We need a sentence showing how you want to use the word -- especially because you want metaphorical.

Comment: [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conductible) online only gives the definition of "adjective; see 'conduct'" but the example sentences do correspond with *able to conduct* in terms of the conducting material, rather than the substance or property that is *able to be conducted*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use "transmissible" or "transmittable"

> transmit verb
>   1a : to send or convey from one person or place to another : FORWARD
>   b
>   : to cause or allow to spread: such as
>   (1) : to convey by or as if by inheritance or heredity : HAND DOWN
>   (2) : to convey (infection) abroad or to another

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transmitted

It does have a connotation of referring to disease, though.

Other words to consider would be "conveyable" and "mobile".

Answer (score 1):

It's not an exact synonym, but heat and electricity are both said to be "**transferable**" (which also works in a general or metaphorical sense).